# How to use Jest with ES6 feature in Webpack

Tags: webpack, jestjs

When I use ES6 feature like `import` and run jest, I get this error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

And it recommends

```
 Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

I don't need transform, when I use Webpack. But looks like I need it for using Jest. How do I do it? How can I use `transform` option in config?

All I have Jest related in package.json is

```
"jest": {
        "verbose": true
    },
"scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the document [Using with webpack 2](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#using-with-webpack-2). You need to configure babel to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by:

- Installing `babel-jest` and `babel-preset-es2015`
- Adding `.babelrc` file with following presets

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

- Adding following transform option in jest configuration

```
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
        }
    },
```